# html php not properly aligning for each column

Tags: php

I m trying to run two loops the first query in retrieves the column .The second query takes the primary id of the first table and executes the query.
Final result should be like given in the image

[image]
Im not able to give the proper alignment

Below is the code

```
<table  width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"   >
<tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
    <td>col4/td>
  </tr>
<?php 

$mast = mysql_query("select * from table1 where av_master_id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'");
      while($res_mas= mysql_fetch_assoc($mast))
      {
      ?>
      <tr>
    <td><?php echo $res_mas['col1'];?></td>
    <?php 
     $room=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE  av_room_id='".$res_mas['av_room_id']."'");

     while($res_room= mysql_fetch_assoc($room))
      {
      ?>

    <td><?php echo $res_room['col2'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res_room['col3'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $res_room['col4'];?></td>


    </td>



    </tr><tr>

  <?php }?>
   </tr>

  <?php } ?>



  </table>
```

Comment: You have a typo:         <td>col4/td> should be     <td>col4</td>

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and your code is highly inefficient. Nested query loops should generally be avoided and rewritten as a single `JOIN`ed operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"   >
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4/td>
    </tr>
<?php 

$mast = mysql_query("select * from table1 where av_master_id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'");
while($res_mas = mysql_fetch_assoc($mast)) {
    $room = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE  av_room_id='".$res_mas['av_room_id']."'");

    $count = 0;
    while($res_room= mysql_fetch_assoc($room)) {
        $count += 1;
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $count === 1 ? $res_mas['col1'] : "";?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res_room['col2'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res_room['col3'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res_room['col4'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
</table>
```

*(untested)*